# Creating dummy variable depending on year and category in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dummy-variable

this is my first time posting a question here, so please let me know if my question is lacking anyway.

Let's say I have the following dataframe where "Value" contains only integer 1 or 2. Basically, I want to create a column("Desired") with a dummy variable where 1 happens when firm has remained with Value=1 since the beginning of its appearance. Once the firm has Value=2, the dummy variable should be 0 even if the firm reverts back to Value=1.

| Firm_ID | Year | Value | Desired |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0000001 | 2000 | 1 | 1 |
| 0000001 | 2001 | 1 | 1 |
| 0000001 | 2002 | 2 | 0 |
| 0000001 | 2003 | 2 | 0 |
| 0000001 | 2004 | 1 | 0 |
| 0000001 | 2005 | 1 | 0 |
| 0000002 | 2000 | 2 | 0 |
| 0000002 | 2001 | 2 | 0 |
| 0000002 | 2002 | 2 | 0 |
| 0000003 | 2000 | 1 | 1 |
| 0000003 | 2001 | 1 | 1 |
| 0000003 | 2002 | 1 | 1 |
| 0000003 | 2003 | 1 | 1 |

```
d = {'firm_id': ["0000001" , "0000001","0000001","0000001","0000001","0000001","0000002","0000002","0000002","0000003",
                "0000003","0000003","0000003"], 
     'year': [2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2000,2001,2002,2000,2001,2002,2003],
    'Value':[1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Currently, the code I am running is the following.

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    firm = df.loc[i,'firm_id']
    year = df.loc[i,'year']
    temp_df = df[df['firm_id']==firm]
    
    if (temp_df.groupby(['year']).max()[['Value']].max() == 2)[0]: # At some point this firm becomes Value==2
        
        # Get Earliest Year of becoming Value==2
        year_df = temp_df.groupby(['year']).max()[['Value']]
        ch_year = year_df[year_df['Value']==2].index.min() # Year the firm becomes Value==2
        
        if year >= ch_year :
            df.loc[i,'Desired'] = 0
        else : 
            df.loc[i,'Desired'] = 1
    else :# They always remain Value==1
         df.loc[i,'Desired']=1
```

However, this code is taking too long for the size of my current dataframe.
Is there a more efficient way of code that I could use?

Comment: @eshirvana Could you clarify a bit? Would the dataframe I provided as an example not be enough?

Comment: @eshirvana Thank you for your input. I tried my best to put it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# df = df.sort_values(["firm_id", "year"])
df.Value.ne(1).groupby(df.firm_id).cumsum().lt(1).astype(int)
#     Value
# 0    1
# 1    1
# 2    0
# 3    0
# 4    0
# 5    0
# 6    0
# 7    0
# 8    0
# 9    1
# 10   1
# 11   1
# 12   1
```